# Wikipedia: How to get the number of page visits for all pages

Tags: wikipedia, dump, wikipedia-api

I want to get the amount of Wikipedia page visits for a distinctive time period for all pages of the English version.

Is that information included in one of the dump files?

Can I use the Wikipedia Web API or Wikidata SPARQL API to obtain that info?

I googled, read the Wikipedia Web API specs and downloaded and inspected some of the Wikipedia dump files, but couldn't find the information.

Comment: what have you done so far? What api are referring/endpoint to?

Comment: I googled, read the Wikipedia Web API specs and downloaded and inspected some of the Wikipedia dump files, but couldn't find the information.

Comment: I am referring to the Wikipedia data dumps, the Wikipedia Web API and the Wikidata SPARQL API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API specifically for collecting page view data. See https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Analytics/AQS/Pageviews for details and examples. If I understand your question correctly, then changing the dates in this call will give you the desired results, although you will need to sum daily values: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/aggregate/en.wikipedia/all-access/all-agents/daily/2015100100/2015103000